# Insert date of new record into database using asp.net with VB

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I'm working on a webapp project. I've added a function for the teacher to add exams. What I need is:

When the teacher adds a new exam record using a DetailsView, the date should be automatically inserted into the date columnn in the exams table in the database.

Here is the code :

```
Protected Sub DetailsView1_ItemInserted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsViewInsertedEventArgs) Handles DetailsView1.ItemInserted

    Dim conn As New SqlConnection()
    conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MCQQUIZZES").ConnectionString

    Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO [Exams] VALUES(@Dateadded) "
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, conn)

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dateadded", Date.Now.ToString)

    conn.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    conn.Close()



End Sub
```

the error massege :

```
Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.
```

any help??

Comment: Obviously the `Exams` table has more than one column. What other columns exist in the table? Why aren't you populating them too? What good is a row where the only piece of information is when the row was added? If you are relying on default population of the other columns, then (and basically always) you should include the column list in your `INSERT`. Also you should generally avoid `AddWithValue()`, and use `Add()` where you can specify the exact data type.

Comment: i am using DetailsView with "insert button" to insert values to the other columns , so the "date column" which i need to insert its value automatically when the teacher pressing insert button

Comment: Not sure I follow. Teacher presses "insert" so you insert a row, *then* you have a form where they fill in the details, and when they submit *that* form, then you perform an update? How do you know which row to update? Your code above doesn't have any way to locate it. Why bother with the insert at all until they've filled in the whole form?

Answer (score 0):

Provide Column Names in Insert command

INSERT INTO Table(Col1, Col2) VALUES (value1,value2)

Comment: I did this :  "INSERT INTO Exams(Dateadded) VALUES(@Dateadded) "

Comment: and i got this error message: Incorrect syntax near ')'

Comment: @HOD does `Exams` have a trigger? That error message shouldn't come from the code you've shown in that comment.

Answer (score 0):

Please change the query in code.

INSERT INTO [Exams] (date) VALUES(getdate())